# SQL: join on foreign key between two tables and return only count of items; not actual items

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, left-join

I know there's lots of questions similar to this out there. I'm writing my first SQL query; and I've been looking through SO but I can't find out specifically what I'm doing wrong, because to me, they look the same as the answers here.

I have three tables:

- disease: has columns: id, name, stage (info about different diseases)
- drug: has columns: id, name, other info about the drugs (info about different drugs)
- disease_drug_link: has foreign key: disease_id (from disease), drug_id (from drug) and other info (info about which drugs to use on which disease).

I want to return, for each disease, the number of drugs for that disease so that i can make a graph; this info is linked together in the disease_drug_link table.

I wrote this as a draft, but I'm just struggling with it:

```
SELECT DP.*, PA.*
FROM disease as DP
LEFT JOIN disease_drug_link as PA
ON DP.id = PA.drug_id
#group by PA.drug_id #### (conn=773299) Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause
#group by DP.drug_id #### (conn=773299) You have an error in your SQL syntax
#group by PA.id ### (conn=773299) You have an error in your SQL syntax
#group by DP.id ### (conn=773299) You have an error in your SQL syntax
limit 10
```

Can someone demonstrate the correct way to do this?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. PS You have a syntax error. Read the grammar & manual. Show that constituent subexpressions are OK.

Comment: When you get a result that you don't expect, stop trying to find your overall goal & find out what your misunderstanding is.--Isolate the first misunderstood subexpression & its input & output & learn what misconception, typo, wrong reasoning, etc led to it. (Debugging fundamental.) Ask 1 (clear) (non-duplicate) question per post. Your 1st error is a faq. Before considering posting please always google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT DP.ID, COUNT(PA.drug_id) as num_drugs
FROM disease DP LEFT JOIN
     disease_drug_link as PA
     ON DP.id = PA.drug_id
GROUP BY DP.ID;
```

If you want additional columns from `DP`, then in most databases you would add them to the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT DP.ID, DP.NAME, COUNT(PA.drug_id) as num_drugs
FROM disease DP LEFT JOIN
     disease_drug_link as PA
     ON DP.id = PA.drug_id
GROUP BY DP.ID, DP.NAME;
```